# How to sizing and center div with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my page:
[image: screeshot]

I want that the page elements will display in this way on dektop:
[image: desktop]

And on mobile:
[image: mobile]

This is the HTML code:

```html
<div class="page-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row mb-5">
      <div id="youtube_ifram" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/m2KVWytDGb0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lgozQO7NOU4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TVuumNBGYNg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the bootstrap documentation, you can use the `justify-content-center` on your main row to center the contents.

```
<div class="page-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-6">
      <div id="youtube_ifram" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">        
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/m2KVWytDGb0" frameborder="0"   allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lgozQO7NOU4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TVuumNBGYNg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this Css to your html

```css
.embed-responsive{
    width: 23%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-section">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row mb-5">
   <div id="youtube_ifram" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/m2KVWytDGb0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   </div>
   <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lgozQO7NOU4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   </div>
   <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TVuumNBGYNg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   </div>
     </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bootstrap sizing guide:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/sizing/

Answer (score 0):

You need to centre the div, and specify the "myclass", width accordingly according to your need. For mobile view just add a media query and set the min-width to 100%, I have a added a fiddle file along-with, hope that helps here is the fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/q7absh8e/3/

```
<div class="page-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
  <div class="myclass">
  <div id="youtube_ifram" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/m2KVWytDGb0" frameborder="0"   allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lgozQO7NOU4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TVuumNBGYNg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the css file

```
.myclass{
   display:table;
   text-align:center;
   margin:0 auto;
   min-width:640px;
    }

iframe{
   width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use bootstrap 4 you can use **w-75** and  **m-auto**

```
   <div class="page-section">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row mb-5 ">
                <div id="youtube_ifram" class="embed-responsive w-50 m-auto embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/m2KVWytDGb0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="embed-responsive w-50 m-auto embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lgozQO7NOU4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="embed-responsive w-50 m-auto embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TVuumNBGYNg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>

            </div>
         </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try these codes:

```
text-align:center;
float:none;
display:inline-block;
```